# Using context managers for recovering from celery's SoftTimeLimitExceeded

Tags: python, celery

I am trying to set a maximum run time for my celery jobs.

I am currently recovering from exceptions with a context manager. I ended up with code very similar to this snippet:

```
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded

class Manager:

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, error_type, error, tb):
        if error_type == SoftTimeLimitExceeded:
            logger.info('job killed.')
            # swallow the exception
            return True


@task
def do_foo():
    with Manager():
        run_task1()
        run_task2()
        run_task3()
```

**What I expected:**

If `do_foo` times out in `run_task1`, the logger logs, the SoftTimeLimitExceeded exception is swallowed, the body of the manager is skipped, the job ends without running `run_task2` and `run_task3`.

**What I observe:**
`do_foo` times out in `run_task1`, SoftTimeLimitExceeded is raised, the logger logs, the SoftTimeLimitExceeded exception is swallowed **but** `run_task2` and `run_task3` are running nevertheless.

I am looking for an answer to following two questions:

1. Why is `run_task2` still executed when SoftTimeLimitExceeded is raised in `run_task1` in this setting?
2. Is there an easy way to transform my code so that it can performs as expected?

Comment: softtimelimit is here to "notify" that the task is running longer and you can handle that exception/error somehow... what you want is probably just [time_limit](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-task_time_limit)

Comment: @MazelTov, since I need to do some cleanup logic before the job is killed, I actually need to work with the soft limit.

Comment: I tested the code and it actually behaves as expected. My original code accidentally had two nested `Manager` blocks which caused the unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1):

### Cleaning up the code

This code is pretty good; there's not much cleaning up to do.

- You shouldn't return `self` from `__enter__` if the context manager isn't designed to be used with the `as` keyword.
- `is` should be used when checking classes, since they are singletons...
- but you should prefer `issubclass` to properly emulate exception handling.

Implementing these changes gives:

```
from celery.exceptions import SoftTimeLimitExceeded

class Manager:
    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, error_type, error, tb):
        if issubclass(error_type, SoftTimeLimitExceeded):
            logger.info('job killed.')
            # swallow the exception
            return True

@task
def do_foo():
    with Manager():
        run_task1()
        run_task2()
        run_task3()
```

### Debugging

I created a mock environment for debugging:

```
class SoftTimeLimitExceeded(Exception):
    pass

class Logger:
    info = print
logger = Logger()
del Logger

def task(f):
    return f

def run_task1():
    print("running task 1")
    raise SoftTimeLimitExceeded

def run_task2():
    print("running task 2")

def run_task_3():
    print("running task 3")
```

Executing this and then your program gives:

```
>>> do_foo()
running task 1
job killed.
```

This is the expected behaviour.

### Hypotheses

I can think of two possibilities:

1. Something in the chain, probably `run_task1`, is asynchronous.
2. `celery` is doing something weird.

I'll run with the second hypothesis because I can't test the former.

I've been bitten by the obscure behaviour of a combination between context managers, exceptions and coroutines before, so I know what sorts of problems it causes. This seems like one of them, but I'll have to look at `celery`'s code before I can go any further.

Edit: I can't make head nor tail of `celery`'s code, and searching hasn't turned up the code that raises `SoftTimeLimitExceeded` to allow me to trace it backwards. I'll pass it on to somebody more experienced with `celery` to see if they can work out how it works.

Comment: thanks for suggestions for code improvement. Much appreciated. I agree that the mock without celery works. Everything should be synchronous. Guess it is celery after all?

Comment: @cel Probably. Try substituting different parts of the mock for parts of `celery` and see what happens. When does the problem go away? That will help you to narrow down the problem _slightly_.